# if map.insert fails how check its failure without using bad_alloc

Tags: c++

If inside my code i am having a

```
class A;
A ob;
pair<map<int,A>::iterator,bool> ret;
ret=map.insert(pair<int,A>(1,ob));
```

If map fails to insert the ob because of out of memory, it will throw bad_alloc
but is there any other way to check whether insert failed or not because i have a restriction to not use namespace and exception handling.
Can't we use some kind of NULL pointer comparision statement?

Comment: Why catch this error? What will you do when the program is out of memory?

Comment: I have to deallocate the object which i was about to insert in the memory.After that i will clear the map itself.

Comment: You can't really opt out of exception handling in standard C++. Certainly you already violated the "no namespace" part when you used `std::map`. But those two "rules" are best violated anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The standard library reports failure to allocate memory by throwing `std::bad_alloc`. And while you are able to get around that with `new(nothrow)`, you can't do that with standard library classes.

Exception handling is part of C++; it is not an *optional* part of C++. Exceptions are the standard C++ way of handling erroneous conditions. I understand that you're working in an environment that doesn't allow you to catch exceptions, but you then have to accept that you're working in an environment that doesn't allow you to use all of C++. So there will be limitations on what you can do.

It should be noted that, unless you're using a custom allocator, it's unlikely that recovering from an "unable to allocate" error would be something easy to implement. Being unable to allocate memory would only happen because your application ran out of memory. In that case, just let the exception be thrown; since you don't use exceptions, it will escape `main` and cause your program to crash. Which is exactly what you want to happen.

If you do have some way to survive running out of allocatable address space, there's not much you can do if you can't catch exceptions. C++ standard library classes are designed to work with C++, and that means all of it. Including exceptions.

Comment: ok...but in my case i cannot let the program terminate so i guess i have to use some other way..

Comment: @gold: We can give better answers if we know you had such constraints. But your profile shows you're a student; what kind of safety critical device are you working on? That's the only kind of program which shouldn't terminate. Even for an assembly line, the best course of action when out of memory is a clean shutdown.

Comment: @gold: OK, your program couldn't allocate memory. Exactly how to you plan to recover from this? Even if you got back a NULL pointer or whatever you want, what would you actually *do* to recover? Just about every new memory allocation you do will now *fail*, since your system is out of memory. What's your plan for continuing the execution of your program when it is out of memory?

Comment: This code is a part of server so we can't let it terminate..I just need a check for this condition so that the object that i allocated before is deallocated and and i safely return from the function..

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to use exception handling? Reconsider this. Parts of the C++ standard library use exceptions internally - this means you can't turn off exceptions using a compiler switch. If exceptions are enabled, you might as well use them - or of course you can implement your own exception-free standard library.

Comment: I can use but it will include more risk in project and besides it will throw the bad_alloc which is in namespace and i also don't want to include the namespace because it is not used in whole project and may lead to other complications.

Comment: @gold: You don't want to "include the namespace"? You're *already using* `std::map`. The "include the namespace" ship has *sailed*. You're already using namespaces. And in point of fact, you're using the *same* namespace that `std::bad_alloc` belongs to. You seem to have a strong fear and lack of understanding of how C++ works. Namespaces aren't something to be afraid of; what "complications" are you concerned about? And exceptions should only be feared if you're programming poorly (not using RAII and other good C++ idioms).